# Moving Eloquent Date Columns (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) to a Related Table

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to move the `created_at`, `updated_at` & `deleted_at` columns in a  Laravel Eloquent model/table to a related table?

The reason I ask is that I want to use this functionality on a table that I cannot change the schema of. As such, I was hoping I could set up a 1-to-1 relationship to a `metadata` table containing these columns. This would give me their benefits without having to alter the original table.

Comment: i guess that you can't move this fields into other table, but you still can update time in you parent related model
`class Comment extends Model {

    protected $touches = ['post'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

}`

Answer (score 0):

you could set `public $timestamps = false;` in the model, but that would only fix half the problem, getting a 1-1 relationship would still require a schema change.

i'm thinking you could have a many-many relationship with the metadata (even though you won't add more than one metadata per post), but that would enable you to have a post_metadata table with the pivots.